# The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

I am working with .net core 5. I have folder structure like below.

- Project
- Project core
- Project business
- Project infrastructure

In "Project", System namespace working fine. But in other "Project" directory it shows error for namespace "System"

Here is the one which i am getting in output

- NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors

Few more errors in error list i am facing are as below

[image]

Comment: At a guess: you've edited your NuGet package sources, and deleted the default nuget.org one? Also look at the Output window (under Build), that will give you errors in the order that they occurred, which lets you focus on the root one(s) and ignore the fallout

Comment: By adding nuget.org, It has been resolved. Thank you.